# how to get sub-index value of array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

We have array like this

```
[
    [6:02:48 , 06:06:20, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, kuja], 
    [06:06:20, 06:15:25, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, rahu], 
    [06:15:25, 06:23:30, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, guru],
    [06:23:30, 06:33:05, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, shani], 
    [06:33:05, 06:41:40, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, budha], 
    [06:41:40, 06:45:12, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, kethu],
    [06:45:12, 06:55:18, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, shukra]
]
```

When we print array upsublist.get(o);
Output come like this `[6:02:48 , 06:06:20, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, kuja]`

We need get only one value like `kuja or rahu or guru`  .Please tell me .How to get Only one  value

We tried like this `upsublist.get(o).get(4)`
We got like this [image]

Answer (score 1):

If `[6:02:48 , 06:06:20, 2015-03-24, Tuesday, kuja]` is an array and it's length is always 5, you can simply write `upsublist.get(o)[4]` to get the last element. If it's an ArrayList, you can write `upsublist.get(o).get(4)`.

If the length is not fixed, you have to find the index of the last element - `upsublist.get(o)[upsublist.get(o).length - 1]`.

Comment: we not get We tried like this 
upsublist.get(o).get(4)

Comment: We create array like this ArrayList upsublist = new ArrayList(); Please help me

Comment: @PavanAlapati What's the type of the inner list? Is it an ArrayList? What happens when you try `upsublist.get(o).get(4)`?

Comment: @PavanAlapati But what is the type of the elements you add to upsublist ?

Comment: innerList is List.
ArrayList upsublist = new ArrayList();List sublistup = new ArrayList();

Comment: @PavanAlapati And what happens when you try what I suggested?

Comment: When Places this upsublist.get(o).get(4). it's asking calender.

Comment: Please look my code now We add image what we got When we placed this upsublist.get(o).get(4);Please help me

Comment: @PavanAlapati It looks like you are trying to assign  upsublist.get(o).get(4) to an int, but based on the content of the list you displayed above, it contains Strings (such as kuja, rahu, etc...). You can't assign a String to an int variable.

Comment: "upsublist.get(o)."  again get  not comeing.We placed String also but only one get is come

Comment: Wait, are you trying get(o) or get(0)? It should be get(0) (unless you have an int variable called o)

Comment: we tried String s1=upsublist.get(0).get(4); but after upsublist.get(0) again get not working for me

Comment: @PavanAlapati "not working" is not a good enough description. Either it doesn't pass compilation or it throws an exception. If it does either of these things, what error/exception are you seeing?

Comment: ok my problem is  after upsbulist. this we got Get we write upsbulist.get(0). we don't got get .So Second get is error